# Let user choose between AccessType.DROPBOX and AccessType.APP_FOLDER

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I have developed an Android application with Dropbox support which uses AccessType.DROPBOX to initialize its session, so I configured the app in the Dropbox developers console to be "Full Dropbox". Now some users would prefer not to give the app full access to their Dropbox but rather copy the files they want to use with the app into something like apps/MyAppName.

Is there any way I could ask the user and then either use AccessType.DROPBOX or AccessType.APP_FOLDER? If I simply build my session with AccessType.APP_FOLDER, the Authentication dialog still asks for full dropbox, probably because it's configured like this in the Developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option that I just found is to configure two apps in the Dropbox console and add a second intent filter in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- db- followed by app key -->
            <data android:scheme="db-APPKey1" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- db- followed by app key -->
            <data android:scheme="db-APPKey2" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I hope Dropbox will allow this second app for production stage...

Comment: This is the right answer... have two different app keys. You'll have to let the user pick which they want to use before you start the authorization flow.